# how to sort json in object in object order using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

hey i'm trying to sort this json.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1.1",
            "parentId": "1",
        },
        {
            "id": "1.2",
            "parentId": "1",
        },
        {
            "id": "1.3",
            "parentId": "1",
        },
        {
            "id": "1.4",
            "parentId": "1",
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.1",
            "parentId": "1.1",
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.2",
            "parentId": "1.1",
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.3",
            "parentId": "1.1",
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.1.1",
            "parentId": "1.1.1",
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.1.2",
            "parentId": "1.1.1",
        },

    ]
}
```

the json should be sorted in tree format. like object will come under object if object's parentid matches the other object's id and so on to nth level.

The expected output should be like:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1.1",
            "parentId": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "1.1.1",
                    "parentId": "1.1",
                    "children": [
                         {
                             "id": "1.1.1.1",
                             "parentId": "1.1.1",
                             "children": []
                         },
                         {
                             "id": "1.1.1.2",
                             "parentId": "1.1.1",
                             "children": []
                         },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1.1.2",
                    "parentId": "1.1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "1.1.3",
                    "parentId": "1.1",
                    "children": []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1.2",
            "parentId": "1",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "1.3",
            "parentId": "1",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "1.4",
            "parentId": "1",
            "children": []
        },
    ]
}
```

i tried but it is displaying upto 3 level only.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
  var json = JSON.parse(`{
    "id": "1",
    "parentId": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1.1",
            "parentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.2",
            "parentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.3",
            "parentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.4",
            "parentId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1.1.1",
            "parentId": "1.1"
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.2",
            "parentId": "1.1"
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.3",
            "parentId": "1.1"
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.1.1",
            "parentId": "1.1.1"
        },
         {
            "id": "1.1.1.2",
            "parentId": "1.1.1"
        }  
    ]
}`);

  var dummyParnt = json.children;
  var dummyChild = json.children;

  var dataGrand= json;
  
  var data=[];

  var init = function() {
   var children=[];
   dataGrand.children=[];

   var k,j=0;

   
   for(var i in dummyParnt){

    if(dummyParnt[i].parentId ==  json.id){

     dataGrand.children[j] = dummyParnt[i];
     dataGrand.children[j].children =[];
     
     k=0;
        for(var a in dummyChild){


         if(dummyParnt[i].id == dummyChild[a].parentId){

          dataGrand.children[j].children[k] = dummyChild[a];
          k++;
         }
        }
        j++;
    }
    
   }
   
   console.log(dataGrand,"datagrand");

          var tableHTML = '<table id="location" border=\'1\'></table>';
         var trHTML = '';

         trHTML += '<tr><td>' + dataGrand.id + '</td></td><td></td><td></tr>';
         
for(var i in dataGrand.children){
    
    trHTML += '<tr><td></td><td>' + dataGrand.children[i].id + '</td></td><td></tr>';
    
    for(var j in dataGrand.children[i].children){
    
    trHTML += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td>' + dataGrand.children[i].children[j].id + '</td></tr>';
    
};
    
};

         $('body').append(tableHTML);
  
$('#location').append(trHTML);
  }
     init();
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
     
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you reached till 3rd level as am seeing your updated code.. try to put one more for loop

Comment: @Varsha i want it to sort till nth level of nested object.

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing a logic try it out hope it works as expected..

> For this you create a array of id's and apply this function to sort
>   that array and then based on this sorted array of id's you can push
>   object into a new array which will be the desired output.

**1)** Get Array of id's - `_.pluck(YOURLIST, 'id');`

OR if you don't want to use underscore.js then, use for loop inside for loop based on length

```
var arrayOfIds = [];
function getLeaf(YOURLIST) {
    for (i=0; i > YOURLIST.length; i++) {
        arrayOfIds.push(YOURLIST[i].id);
        for (j=0; j > YOURLIST[i].length; j++) {
            arrayOfIds.push(YOURLIST[i][j].id);
            return getLeaf(YOURLIST[i][j]); // <- recursive call
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** Call this below function to sort above created array.

```
function compareAndSort(x, y) {
   var xParts = x.split('.');
   var yParts = y.split('.');
   var max = xParts.length > yParts.length ? yParts.length : xParts.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      var xInt = parseInt(xParts[i]);
      var yInt = parseInt(yParts[i]);
      if (xInt < yInt) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (yInt < xInt) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (i == max -1) {
        if (yParts.length > xParts.length) {
          return -1;
        }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**3)** Based on new sorted arrayList, create a new desired output array of objects by pushing your object based on sorted list of id's.

Comment: the issue is i'm getting the logic to reach the child object in child's object. can you explain little bit deep here with your solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer.. if you need further help.. let me know. Thanks

Comment: hi, it work if the objects are in same hierarchy ,but if you see the data json the main parent object contains the object which can be child or child of child.

Comment: and i cant use anything else than jquery and javascript, cant use underscorejs.

Comment: Ok! 1st step you can achieve using for loop inside for loop based on length and keep pushing id's. I have edited my answer.